# What is the name of this formula? $n=\left(\frac{1.96\sigma}{p-\mu}\right)^2$

Tags: soft-question

I know this is a derivation from the central limit theorem and used to calculate the number of times one needs to play a game with a buy-in and end up with a positive profit.

$$n=\left(\frac{1.96\sigma}{p-\mu}\right)^2$$

Is there a name for it?

Comment: Looks like a 95 percent confidence interval formula

Comment: @Paul: reminds of, but is not.